# Zooming in on a UI element causes it to become unsharp/pixelated on iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, pinchzoom

I am using Xamarin.Forms.

On iOS, when using the pinch gesture below to zoom in on a Label (for example), the Label turns pixelated instead of updating and staying sharp.

On Android, this doesn't happen and the Label stays sharp and visible, no matter how much I zoom in on it.

Is there a way to make behave on iOS as it does with Android?

Edit: this behaviour can also be observed simply by raising the scale of a visual element, on Android it looks good but on iOS it turns pixelated. I assume my problem lies here but I'm not sure how to tackle it yet.

The pinch gesture implementation I use to zoom in with:

```
public class ZoomWithPinch : ContentView
{ 

     public ZoomWithPinch()
     {
            var pinchGesture = new PinchGestureRecognizer();
            pinchGesture.PinchUpdated += OnPinchUpdated;
            GestureRecognizers.Add(pinchGesture);
     }

     double currentScale = 1;
     double startScale = 1;
     double xOffset = 0;
     double yOffset = 0;

     private void OnPinchUpdated(object sender, PinchGestureUpdatedEventArgs e)
     {
            if (e.Status == GestureStatus.Started)
            {

                startScale = Content.Scale;
                Content.AnchorX = 0;
                Content.AnchorY = 0;
            }

            if (e.Status == GestureStatus.Running)
            {
                currentScale += (e.Scale - 1) * startScale;
                currentScale = Math.Max(1, currentScale);

                double renderedX = Content.X + xOffset;
                double deltaX = renderedX / Width;
                double deltaWidth = Width / (Content.Width * startScale);
                double originX = (e.ScaleOrigin.X - deltaX) * deltaWidth;

                double renderedY = Content.Y + yOffset;
                double deltaY = renderedY / Height;
                double deltaHeight = Height / (Content.Height * startScale);
                double originY = (e.ScaleOrigin.Y - deltaY) * deltaHeight;

                double targetX = xOffset - (originX * Content.Width) * (currentScale - startScale);
                double targetY = yOffset - (originY * Content.Height) * (currentScale - startScale);

                Content.TranslationX = Math.Min(0, Math.Max(targetX, -Content.Width * (currentScale - 1)));
                Content.TranslationY = Math.Min(0, Math.Max(targetY, -Content.Height * (currentScale - 1)));

                Content.Scale = currentScale;
            }

            if (e.Status == GestureStatus.Completed)
            {
                xOffset = Content.TranslationX;
                yOffset = Content.TranslationY;
            }
    }

public void OnPanUpdated(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (Content.Scale == 1)
            {
                return;
            }

            switch (e.StatusType)
            {
                case GestureStatus.Running:

                    double newX = (e.TotalX * Scale) + xOffset;
                    double newY = (e.TotalY * Scale) + yOffset;

                    double width = (Content.Width * Content.Scale);
                    double height = (Content.Height * Content.Scale);

                    bool canMoveX = width > Application.Current.MainPage.Width;
                    bool canMoveY = height > Application.Current.MainPage.Height;

                    if (canMoveX)
                    {
                        double minX = (width - (Application.Current.MainPage.Width / 2)) * -1;
                        double maxX = Math.Min(Application.Current.MainPage.Width / 2, width / 2);

                        if (newX < minX)
                        {
                            newX = minX;
                        }

                        if (newX > maxX)
                        {
                            newX = maxX;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        newX = 0;
                    }

                    if (canMoveY)
                    {
                        double minY = (height - (Application.Current.MainPage.Height / 2)) * -1;
                        double maxY = Math.Min(Application.Current.MainPage.Width / 2, height / 2);

                        if (newY < minY)
                        {
                            newY = minY;
                        }

                        if (newY > maxY)
                        {
                            newY = maxY;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        newY = 0;
                    }

                    Content.TranslationX = newX;
                    Content.TranslationY = newY;
                    break;
                case GestureStatus.Completed:
                    xOffset = Content.TranslationX;
                    yOffset = Content.TranslationY;
                    break;
            }
        }
}
```

```
<ZoomWithPinch>
    <Grid>
         <Label Text="Test" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</ZoomWithPinch>
```

Comment: seems it is an [known issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/11480) on ios about scaling on image are blurry.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. There even seems to be a fix regarding this but it's only for Xamarin.Forms.Shapes, not all elements in general.

Comment: You can also feedback your problem at github, you will get response when this problem fixed.